# Apache Spark: Hashmap accumulators give type mismatch error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to declare a hashmap as Spark (v0.9.1) accumulator. The docs state that "Spark natively supports accumulators of numeric value types and standard mutable collections..." ([link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/scala-programming-guide.html#accumulators)).

However, this doesn't seem to be working for me when I try to create a HashMap[String, Boolean]:

```
scala> import collection.mutable.HashMap
import collection.mutable.HashMap

scala> val accum = sc.accumulator("test" -> true)(HashMap)
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.type
 required: org.apache.spark.AccumulatorParam[(String, Boolean)]
           val accum = sc.accumulator("test" -> true)(HashMap)
```

Comment: Why are you using a mutable HashMap? Can't you try and design your code in a functional way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you should pass an actual `HashMap[String, String]` rather than `(String, String)`:

`sc.accumulator(HashMap("t" -> true))`

And you may need to write your own accumulator, 'cause I didn't find an out-of-the-box implicit for the `HashMap`:

```
implicit object iHashMap extends AccumulatorParam[HashMap[String, Boolean]] {
  def zero(m: HashMap[String, String]) = HashMap()
  def addInPlace(m1: HashMap[String, Boolean], m2: HashMap[String, Boolean]) = m1 ++ m2 
}
```

The behaviour is probably not what you personally would expect, but I hope you catch the gist.

You may also find some really useful examples here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/60abc252545ec7a5d59957a32e764cd18f6c16b4/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/AccumulatorSuite.scala

Comment: When we try to add to the accumulator using `accumulator += (a -> b)` it throws a compile time error that expected hashmap but found tuple?

Comment: @Sohaib, as I told, you should pass not the tuple but the `Map` instance instead.

Comment: So is the right syntax like `accumulator += Hashmap(a->b)` ?

Comment: @Sohaib, please read my answer, it contains everything you need.

Comment: My implementation of Accumulator param slightly differs from the one given. It is like `AccumulatorParam[mutable.HashMap[String, Long]]`. The example gives me the construct on how to create an accumulator. I also wish to know how to add to it. I also saw the documentation link that you had given but it uses `accumulableCollection` to create accumulators and is different.

Answer (score 7):

I remember having the same issue, here's a small gist to use a `HashMap[String, Int]` as accumulator in Spark: [HashMapParam.scala](https://gist.github.com/fedragon/b22e5d1eee4803c86e53)

If a key `k` already exists in the accumulator with a value `v1` and we try to put `k -> v2` in it, the resulting accumulator will contain `k -> v1 + v2`.

This does not completely answer your question but could be helpful to build your own implementation.

Comment: The gist is buggy at places. For example the addAccumulator method does not compile. Also addAccumulator is not inplace so you need to reassign to accu1 in the example in order to return the complete set.

Comment: Hello, my gist was indeed missing one import (`AccumulableParam`) so it wouldn't compile out of the box... besides this, why do you say that it doesn't work? I created a small project with some tests and they are all green, would you please take a look? https://github.com/fedragon/hashmapparam

Comment: I had a similar problem and created a solution using the new AccumulatorV2  API. See https://gist.github.com/oschrenk/78419ff59e1d0a42692a0e57d5b9a491